# histroy.push() is not working in react router, if my base route is same

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have seen so many questions but haven't got the answer.
When i do `history.push('/user')` when i am on `'/dashboard'`, it works great because my base route is different i.e *`user!=dashboard`*. But when i am on route `'/user'` and now i want to go to `history.push('/user/87')`. Here the weird thing happens as base route is same *`user===user`*, my url change but my component did not render again. I have use the `<Link>` thing which the react-router-dom provides but it doesn't work too.

here is my root thing,

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; //"^5.0.1"

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Please provide the solution it would be great help.

Comment: why are you pushing particular history.push('/user/87') instead of history.push('/user').

Comment: It's requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one trick with my colleague, we can use **`getDerivedStateFromProps`** and **`componentDidUpdate`** life cycles

```
state = {
  currentUrl: this.props.match.url,
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    let updatedState = {};

    if (props.match.url !== state.currentUrl) {
      updatedState.currentUrl = props.match.url;
    }

    return updatedState;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.url !== this.state.currentUrl) {
      // re-initiate your state so that it can run your render lifecycle
      this.setInitialState(); 
    }
  }
```

We can also use **useEffect** hook by providing `[this.props.match.url]` in second argument so that when ever your url updates you can set your state.

Answer (score -1):

maybe do a this.forceUpdate() right after you push or use :params

Comment: As i am not updating the state, just want to update the history by push method to make component re-render as normal.